# Apache camel file example not working

Tags: apache-camel

I just implemented this hello world example and it's not working. The code compiles and starts but nothing happens when I copy the files. I cannot figure out what I have done wrong.

```
Main main = new Main();

System.out.println("---- ENTER ----");


MyRouteBuilder route = new MyRouteBuilder();

main.addMainListener(new Events()); 
main.addRouteBuilder(route);
main.run();



public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder{

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {


    System.out.println("Setting up route builder");

    from("file:C:\\datafiles\\input? 
       delete=true").to("file:C:\\datafiles\\output");

   }    }
```

Comment: I think your route is correct. When you say nothing happens you mean that you cannot see files at output folder?

Comment: yes, that is correct. The file does not get copied to the output folder or deleted from the input folder.

Comment: Try lowercase c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common trap with Camel examples is that if the files you place in the folder have no content, Camel will wait for them to get content. You can change this behavior with readLockMinLength=0.

Also, your use of Windows backslash will create bad logging at least, so I would use the following format:

```
from("file:///C:/datafiles/input?delete=true&readLockMinLength=0")
```